# Unable to execute SonarQube Provider weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXParserFactory not found

Tags: jenkins, ant, sonarqube

SonarQube reports not generating using sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar

```
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:53)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:48)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:179)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:268)

 Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXParserFactory not found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:134)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:81)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:59)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:134)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.initLogging(IsolatedLauncher.java:71)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.createBatch(IsolatedLauncher.java:52)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 25 more
```

How to solve this error?

I am using the below version:

- SonarQube 4.2
- sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar

Comment: Could you give the Java version and the classpath used by the Ant task ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution the problem is i was using java 6, after changing to java 7 it's working.

Hope this may help others in future.